# Max number of core in Solr multi-core

Tags: solr

We have a system that enables users to create applications and store data on their application. We want to separate the index of each application. We create a core for each application and search on the given application when user make query. Since there isn't any relation between the applications, this solution could perform better than the storing all index together.

I have two questions related to this.

1. Is this a good solution? If not could you please suggest any better solution?
2. Is there a limit on the number of core that I can create on Solr? There will be thousands maybe more application on the system.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, it COULD be a good solution, as always depends on the specific use case\
2. Look at [this jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1028) where Erick mentions a 10k core system...so 
   it seems it could work for you, should need to assess the hardware etc